# breaking hook rules when generating refs with onClick function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am making a section in my app that has tabs. I'm trying to make an `EditorTabs` component, in which each tab corresponds to an instance of an codemirror editor.

I have this Hook:

```
export const useEditor = <T extends Element>({
  init
}: Props): [MutableRefObject<T | null>, EditorView?] => {
  const wrapperRef = useRef<T | null>(null);
  const [editorView, setEditorView] = useState<EditorView>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!wrapperRef.current) return;

    const state = EditorState.create({
      doc: init,
      extensions: [
        markdown({
          base: markdownLanguage,
          addKeymap: true,
          codeLanguages: languages
        }),
        keymap.of([...markdownKeymap])
      ]
    });

    const view = new EditorView({
      state,
      parent: wrapperRef.current
    });

    setEditorView(view);
  }, []);

  return [wrapperRef, editorView];
};
```

This hook creates a new instance of EditorView and a new ref for its container (the editor will appear in the element with the ref).

This is the `EditorTabs` component:

```
const EditorTabs = () => {
  const { viewdata } = useContext(ViewsContext)!;

  return (
    <Tabs className="w-fit">
      <TabsList>
        {viewdata.map(data => (
          <TabsTrigger key={data.id} value={data.id}>
            {data.id}
          </TabsTrigger>
        ))}
      </TabsList>
      {viewdata.map(data => (
        <TabsContent
          key={data.id}
          value={data.id}
          ref={data.wrapperRef}
        ></TabsContent>
      ))}
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

And this is the context that holds all the data

```
export interface ViewData {
  view: EditorView;
  id: string;
  wrapperRef: MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>;
}

type SetViews = Dispatch<SetStateAction<ViewData[]>>;

export const ViewsContext = createContext<{
  viewdata: ViewData[];
  setViewdata: SetViews;
} | null>(null);
```

now, i want it so that with an onclick function, I can add tabs to the component (add a new editor instance in each tab.)

So my idea was to make this array of data and generating all the tabs with `array.map`. The problem is that I can't generate new editors, because i cannot call the useEditor hook in an onClick function, because it results in breaking the rules of hook. This is how I call it now:

```
const Component = () => {
  const openTab = (id: string) => {
    const [wrapperRef, view] = useEditor<HTMLDivElement>({ init: id });

    const data: ViewData = { id, wrapperRef, view: view! };
    setViewdata([...viewdata, data]);
  };
return <Button onClick={() => openTab(randomId)}>add tab</Button>
}
```

(this is set on a button in a separate component)

how can I do? I tried many things, but all led to the same error.